# Is there an azure DevOps API to fetch all lists of work items assigned to a user under and organisation

Tags: azure, api, devops

i am working with azure DevOps API and i was able to integrate with the API to fetch releases, builds and projects, but i  need an azure API endpoint i can call to fetch list of all work items that had been assigned to each users under an organisation(get all workitems by user/organisation), need this to generate a report to my organisation top management staff. Please

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to fetch all lists of work items assigned to a user under an organization.

1. Returning a Single Work Item.

   GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7Bid%7D?api-version=6.0)

When you are requesting for a single work item, you need to pass the specific work Item Id in the URL.

Please take a look at this doc for a sample return response : [Single Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

2. Returns multiple work items for a list of work item ids (Maximum 200)

   GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7Bid%7D?api-version=6.0)

When returning a multiple work items, you need to pass the name of an organization in the API endpoint.

Take a look at this doc for more reference : [Multiple Work Items in a batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, this will help but what i need is an endpoint that will display all work items assigned to me in the organization. there is a table on home page of azure DevOps that displays the information "my work items" tab, it displays all work items. I need this report to show the management all projects and works each developer is working on across the organization. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have an endpoint to work items section, the only way to access it is through the UI or Rest API. You could do a query and then retrieve that query through rest api, you would actually need to do queries per each user per org.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0